# How to change a variable with a command in javascript discord bot

Tags: javascript, variables, discord, discord.js

So, guys, I am trying to change variables in discord.js

what I am making is like that

```
var Version = "10"

bot.on(bot.on("message", message => {
case 'Test'
    messages.channel.send(Version)
break;
})
```

What I am trying to make is 
Change the Version with a command example of a command

> +edit Version 100

And the version variable will be changed and when you type test
it will say 100 not gonna say 10

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you are very new to coding in javascript. I have written out some starter code for you to help you out.

Not everyone will do this for you and I rarely do it as well. We do this because we believe that offering the quick and dirty solution teaches people nothing.

Therefore I would appreciate that you take a look at these links below to learn about why my code does what it does. :)

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

```
var version = "10";

bot.on("message", message => {
    let args = message.split(" ");
    if(args.length === 0) {
        //send error no arguments
        return;
    }
    switch(args[0]) {
        case 'test':
            messages.channel.send(version.toString());
            break;
        case 'version':
            if(args.length < 2) {
                //send error too short message
            } else {
                version = args[1];
            }
            break;
        default:
            //send not found
            break;
    }
});
```